# How to set a file's encoding when writing it out in c#?

Tags: c#, file, encoding

I'm not full certain I understand file encoding completely. If I write out text to a file in c#, how can I set the encoding type of that file? Maybe it's just I do not understand the full spectrum of file encoding.

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(@"c:\test.txt", FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    sw.WriteLine("my text...");
}
```

Comment: You really should read the available overloads for a constructor!

Comment: _"Maybe it's just I do not understand the full spectrum of file encoding."_ Then have yourself a [read](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). :-)

Comment: Your code already sets the encoding. So what is your real question?

Comment: Sorry all, this was sample code I found on another discussion. I didn't actually write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does exactly that - you're writing out text using ISO Latin 1.

Note that there's nothing in the file itself to specify the encoding, unless you're writing out a file which *allows* you to specify that. The file is basically just a sequence of bytes. The encoding you're specifying in your code determines how the *text* you're writing is converted into bytes, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aadshsx.aspx) that accepts an `Encoding` parameter, which you already do, and set the encoding to the one you like.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,512);
{
    sw.WriteLine(""text here);
}
```